# How to prevent Cron Task from writing file on server?

Tags: cron, wget, cron-task

I'm facing this problem : 
When I execute a CRON task from my Web Server with this command :

```
wget https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It creates new files cron.php1, cron.php2, ... in my /root directory and It takes a lot of space. How can I prevent this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-O /dev/null` what will write the output file to /dev/null

`wget -O /dev/null https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Or `-O-` which will output it to stdout.

`wget -O- https://mon-url.com/file/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer:

```
wget --delete-after
```